# Логика кода Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я хочу чтобы куб(игрок) перепрыгивал препятсвия которые идут на него (платформы),
чтобы они ускорялись. Я не знаю что я не так делаю но счетчик доходит до определенного числа и платформы не спавнятся

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject [] plats;
    [SerializeField]
    float speed;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        speed+=.01f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (transform.position.x <= 0f && transform.position.x >= -0.25f)
        {
            Instantiate(plats[0],new Vector3(23f,0,0),Quaternion.identity);
        }

        if(transform.position.x <=-18f)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Советую использовать пуллинг для таких вещей. За место постоянного создания и удаления платформ. А в целом не понятно, что вы хотите и как хотите ускорять, добавьте больше информации в вопрос.

Comment: насколько я понял у вас возрастает скорость и в определенный момент  условие первого ифа уже не срабатывает

Comment: Какое максимальное возможное число?

Answer (score 0):

При достижении какой-то координаты, которая не подходит под условие

```
transform.position.x <= 0f && transform.position.x >= -0.25f
```

спаун перестает происходить, потому что он внутри этого условия.